Data Attribute has double quote
I am using ASP.NET MVC and in my class I have member whose description has double quotes in it like below:
[Display(Name = "Biological "Parent"?")]
public bool? IsParent { get; set; }

Is there any way we can use above method to display double quote in razor view or do I have to just declare label with what I want?
I tried replacing (") with (&quot;) and it just displays "Biological &quot;Parent&quot;" in label text when rendered

Show us your .aspx/.cshtml code where you're rendering the <label>.

@Dai :  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsParent)

Just escape the double-quotes in C#:
[Display(Name = "Biological \"Parent\"?")]
public bool? IsParent { get; set; }

or
[Display(Name = @"Biological ""Parent""?")]
public bool? IsParent { get; set; }

